# Dismissing 3 layers of modal view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

In my application, I have three layers of modal view controllers.

1) So my `rootViewController` is a `tabbar`.

2) On `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I am presenting a `viewController`, say `viewController A` modally above `tabbar`.

3) On click of a button in 'viewController A', I present another `viewController B` modally.

4) And a button action on `viewController B` presents `navigationController` modally with its `rootViewController` as `viewController C`.

5) Finally from `viewController C`, I want to go back to `viewController A`.

I tried using

```
[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in `viewController C`, but it reverts me back to `viewController B` instead of `viewController A`.

How can I revert back to `viewController A`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a complex VC stack. You could as one poster suggested implement a custom dismissView method, but that would be fragile: if you reuse this view, or move it in your app, it will cease functioning, because it relies too much on specific knowledge of how other VCs have configured their state.

You could configure a delegation chain. This would be the standard way to manipulate views: the presenting VC is also responsible for removing anything it presents.

To do so, build a protocol implemented by B, and initialize C with a reference to B. Similarly, initialize B with a reference to A (with potentially the same protocol, depending on any other communication that needs to be passed between them.)

Then when the button is clicked on C, it calls B's delegate method. B unwinds C as appropriate, and calls A's delegate method. A unwinds B as appropriate.

This has the advantage of keeping VC knowledge encapsulated: A knows how it presented B, so it knows how to unpresent it, and B knows how it presented C, and knows how to un-present it. In no case does one VC need to make assumptions about how it was presented by another.

Answer (score 2):

push all the 'modal' views on a navigationControl with a transitionStyle that looks like the modalTransitionStyle..dont reinvent stuff

present all in one modal navigationController Id say :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the view dismissing method like:

```
- (IBAction)dismissView
 {
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];   // dismiss c
   [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; //dismiss b
 }
```

`[self parentViewController]` will return the parent view of `viewControllerC`, that's `viewControllerB`. So it'll dismiss that view too.

Comment: giving the same result..
Viewcontroller B comes to the screen instead of viewcontroller A

Comment: just a try: write `[[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` what happens ?

Comment: nothing at all!!
Stays in the same screen. Damn this is crazy.

Comment: @footyapps27: sorry dude :( I'm also confused. If you get it fixed please post the answer or let me know :)

Comment: Hi @footyapps27 this can be done with some workaround like using some bool ivar for dismissing the view controller b on view will appear :)

Comment: If need more info or logic code I can post it to you as ans or comment just ask for it :)

Comment: If you're targeting iOS 5.0 and up, you can use: - (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^)(void))completion and dismiss the second view controller in the completion block